# Residue theorem for rational function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I try to get the following result but I don't see how to choose the integration paths to apply the residue theorem:

Let $R(z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ a rational function for polynomials $P, Q$ with $\operatorname{deg} Q \geq \operatorname{deg} P + 2$ which has no pole in $(0, \infty)$. Further $R$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z = 0$ or has a pole of order $1$ in $z = 0$. Let $z_1, \dots, z_n$ all singularities of $R$ in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$. Then it holds that
$$\int_0^\infty x^\theta R(x) \, dx = \frac{2 \pi i }{1 - e^{2 \pi i \theta}} \sum_{j = 1}^n \operatorname{res}_{z_j}(z^\theta R(z)).$$
I tried to use a semicircle from $0$ to an abritrarily large $r > 0$ as integration path but I dont get all residues like this. Honestly I have no idea how to get the residue theorem involved here. I would love to see some solutions to the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use a keyhole integration path:

[image]

Besides, define $z^\theta$ as $e^{\theta\log z}$, where $\log$ is the determination of the logarigthm defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,+\infty)$.